# Returns of an Update Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure on my SQL SERVER 2008:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SAVE1]
    @IDKEY float,
    @CPF nvarchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN TRY
    UPDATE people SET NINUMBER = @CPF WHERE IDKEY = (SELECT IDKEY from contact where IDKEY= @IDKEY)
    SELECT 1 as retorno
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT 0 as retorno
END CATCH


END
```

But if I execute with a invalid IDKEY, the return is "1", but I thought would enter in the "CATCH" and return "0". What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: notice: only when an error or exception occurs then the code inside catch block will run

Comment: and why are'nt you just doing `UPDATE people SET NINUMBER = @CPF WHERE IDKEY = @IDKEY`?

Comment: My mistake, they should be different in the example.
UPDATE people SET NINUMBER = @CPF WHERE IDKEY = (SELECT IDKEY from contact where CDKEY= @CDKEY)

Comment: You are using a float as a primary key???

Comment: Yes, I'm using float as primary key. Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is not failing instead it is returning no rows and hence it is returning 1. Try like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SAVE1]
    @IDKEY float,
    @CPF nvarchar(20)
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE people SET NINUMBER = @CPF WHERE IDKEY = (SELECT IDKEY from contact where IDKEY= @IDKEY)
END

IF (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
     SELECT 1 as retorno
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
    SELECT 0 as retorno
END
```

Comment: Works like a charm. And I will use it for others procedures. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It won't throw an exception in this case. Your subquery simply would return no records, and therefore your update statement would execute against zero records. It would not fail though.